# how can I check if someone use the url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to check if someone joins a site page with a specific link.
`For example:` this domain `www.mydom.com` I want to make event tracking if `/people?5555 = people?5555` do something in using `express`, but I search a lot but I didn't find anything

Comment: when user hit `www.mydom.com` you can track system IP and store it in db. in case of url end points make a middleware `app.use("/", (req, res) => { //get Ip and store the IP});`

Answer (score 0):

Express uses what are called midlewares., these are handy as you can use them to capture every request made.

Example.

```js
app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  //req now has the request.
  //make sure you call next here
  next();
});
```

One thing to note, middlewares are executed in order, so make sure you place this middleware before all the requests you want to intercept.   IOW: place before your `app.gets` etc.